# configure: error: 'no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH' while running ./configure when trying to install magic tool

Tags: kubuntu, compiling

`configure: error: 'no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH'` while running ./configure when trying to install magic tool as shown in the below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Surely the instruction told you to install a few things before compiling... And, when asking, always post the exact instruction you've been following and don't post screenshots of code. Copy/past in code fences.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not ready for compiling software on linux yourself, then first check whether the software is available in the standard software repositories. `magic` is, and can conveniently and safely be installed with the command

```
sudo apt install magic
```

It can be uninstalled with a similar command, where you replace `install` by `remove`.

If software is not available in the standard software repositories, then check if the developer provides a private software source (PPA) you can connect to your system, or see whether it is available as an AppImage, or whether pre-compiled binaries are available.

If you must compile your self, then be ready to install your development tools first. The command

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential devscripts
```

will install the basic tools. While compilation sometimes may be rather easy for rather small tools, in other instances, dependencies may be lacking, which you then need to sort out on your own. This can technically be very challenging, even for linux users with thorough experience in system management. So keep this option as the very last.